# Chartjs : is it possible to add border to the datalabel text within the dougnut chart react

Tags: chart.js, react-chartjs-2

Is it possible to add border color to the text.

[image: add border to the text]

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-chartjs-2-doughnut-pie-chart-forked-j3dhsn?file=/src/index.js

Answer (score 2):

You can print text outline/stroke using `textStrokeColor` and `textStrokeWidth` like this. see the [full documentation](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/options.html#options)

```
datalabels: {
  color: "#fff",
  borderColor: "#000",
  textStrokeColor: 'black', // <-- added this
  textStrokeWidth: 5, // <-- added this
  font: {
     size: 14,
     weight: "bold"
  }
}
```

See the edited [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-chartjs-2-doughnut-pie-chart-forked-llnesc?file=/src/index.js). this will output chart like this
[image: edited chart]

Answer (score 0):

The only thin missing in your code is `datalabels.borderWidth`

```
datalabels: {
  color: "#fff",
  borderColor: "#000",
  borderWidth: 2, // <- add this 
  font: {
    size: 14,
    weight: "bold"
  }
}
```

Please take a look at your amended [CodeSanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-chartjs-2-doughnut-pie-chart-forked-64u6j2) to see the result.